# Splitting HSV mask into multiple rectangles

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I created a HSV mask from the image. The result like following:
[image]

My goal is draw muliple rectangles that fit mask height or width, like following:
[image]

I encouter 2 problem.

1. I don't know how to locate the starting and ending point in mask for creating rectangle. If I use for loop to scan though mask row by row, it may split mask into 2 part.
   [image]
2. Sometime, there also contain 2 different mask in one image. How can I draw rectangles?
   [image]

Anyone can give me some suggestion?

Comment: Does your rectangles have an specific size to respect or is there a optimal number of rectangle to draw in each mask ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for your biggest contour (cross-like shape) with `cv2.findContour()`. It returns an array of coordinates of the contour. Then you can search your contour for point that has the highest X coordinate (that being your most right point), lowest X coordinat (most left point), highest Y coordinate (being most bottom point) and lowest Y coordinate (being your highest point). After you have all 4 values you can search the contour again for all points that have that values and append them in 4 different lists which you sort them later so you can get these points as drown on the bottom picture:

[image]

```
cv2.circle(img,(top_vertical[0]), 4, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.circle(img,(top_vertical[-1]), 4, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.circle(img,(bottom_vertical[0]), 4, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.circle(img,(bottom_vertical[-1]), 4, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.circle(img,(left_horizontal[0]), 4, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.circle(img,(left_horizontal[-1]), 4, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.circle(img,(right_horizontal[0]), 4, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.circle(img,(right_horizontal[-1]), 4, (0,0,255), -1)
```

From this point forward I have transformed the lists into numpy arrays as it is easier for me. You can do it any other way.

Then it is just a matter of how many rectangles you want and how do you want to display them. In my example code you have to input how many same size rectangles you want and the last one is the size of what is left. I have first displayed rectangles on Y coordinate (green color) and then on X coordinate, which is divided on two segments (left and right) because they slightly vary in distance and I did not want to draw over the Y coordinate rectangles as they are not drawn on your example image. You can change the logic of writting the rectangles as you wish. Hope it helps a bit or give an idea on how to proceede. Cheers!

Example code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image and search for contours. 
img = cv2.imread('cross.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Select the biggest contour (if you wish to segmentize only the cross-like contour). 
cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Create empty lists for appending key points. 
top_vertical = []
bottom_vertical = []
left_horizontal = []
right_horizontal = []

# Setting the starter values for N, S, E, W. 
top = 10000
bottom = 0
left = 10000
right = 0

# Loop to get highest key values of N, S, E, W.  
for i in cnt:
    y = int(i[:,1])
    x = int(i[:, 0])
    if x < left:
        left = int(x)
    if x > right:
        right = int(x)
    if y < top:
        top = int(y)
    if y > bottom:
        bottom = int(y)

# Loop for appending all points containing key values of N, S, E, W.   
for i in cnt:
    if int(i[:,1]) == top:
        up = (int(i[:,0]), int(i[:,1]))
        top_vertical.append(up)
    if int(i[:,1]) == bottom:
        down = (int(i[:,0]), int(i[:,1]))
        bottom_vertical.append(down)
    if int(i[:,0]) == left:
        l = (int(i[:,0]), int(i[:,1]))
        left_horizontal.append(l)
    if int(i[:,0]) == right:
        r = (int(i[:,0]), int(i[:,1]))
        right_horizontal.append(r)


# Sorting the lists. 
top_vertical.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0])
bottom_vertical.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0])
left_horizontal.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])
right_horizontal.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])

# Optional drawing of key points. 
'''cv2.circle(img,(top_vertical[0]), 4, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.circle(img,(top_vertical[-1]), 4, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.circle(img,(bottom_vertical[0]), 4, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.circle(img,(bottom_vertical[-1]), 4, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.circle(img,(left_horizontal[0]), 4, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.circle(img,(left_horizontal[-1]), 4, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.circle(img,(right_horizontal[0]), 4, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.circle(img,(right_horizontal[-1]), 4, (0,0,255), -1)'''

# Transforming lists to arrays. 
top_vertical = np.array(top_vertical)
bottom_vertical = np.array(bottom_vertical)
left_horizontal = np.array(left_horizontal)
right_horizontal = np.array(right_horizontal)

# Calculating height and weight of the contour.
distance_y = bottom - top
distance_x = right - left

# Inputs for the number of same size segments. 
a = input('Input the number of same size segments in Y coordinate: ')
b = input('Input the number of same size segments in left X coordinate: ')
c = input('Input the number of same size segments in right X coordinate: ')

# Calculation of area per segment and limit for the lenght of combined segments (height and weight) . 
segment_y = distance_y/int(a)
segment_x_reference = int(top_vertical[0,0]) - int(left_horizontal[0,0])
segment_x = segment_x_reference/int(b)
segment_x_right_reference = int(right_horizontal[0,0]) - int(top_vertical[-1,0])
segment_x_right = segment_x_right_reference/int(c)

# Drawing rectangles on the Y axis.
for i in range(1,20):
    sq = int(segment_y)*i
    if sq < distance_y:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(top_vertical[0,0], top_vertical[0,1]),((top_vertical[-1,0]),top_vertical[0,1] + sq),(0,255,0),1)
    else:
        sq = distance_y
        cv2.rectangle(img,(top_vertical[0,0], top_vertical[0,1]),((top_vertical[-1,0]),sq),(0,255,0),1)
        break

# Drawing rectangles on the left side of X axis.   
for i in range(1,20):
    sq = int(segment_x)*i
    if sq < segment_x_reference:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(left_horizontal[0,0], left_horizontal[0,1]),((left_horizontal[0,0])+sq, left_horizontal[-1,1]),(255,0,0),1)
    else:
        sq = segment_x_reference
        cv2.rectangle(img,(left_horizontal[0,0], left_horizontal[0,1]),((left_horizontal[0,0])+sq, left_horizontal[-1,1]),(255,0,0),1)
        break

# Drawing rectangles on the right side of X axis. 
for i in range(1,20):
    sq = int(segment_x_right)*i
    if sq < segment_x_right_reference:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(right_horizontal[0,0], right_horizontal[0,1]),((right_horizontal[0,0])-sq, right_horizontal[-1,1]),(255,0,0),1)
    else:
        sq = segment_x_right_reference
        cv2.rectangle(img,(right_horizontal[0,0], right_horizontal[0,1]),((right_horizontal[0,0])-sq, right_horizontal[-1,1]),(255,0,0),1)
        break

# Displaying result. 
cv2.imshow('img', img)
```

Result:

```
Input the number of same size segments in Y coordinate: 5
Input the number of same size segments in left X coordinate: 2
Input the number of same size segments in right X coordinate: 2
```

[image]

Comment: Inspiring post +1. Will this approach work for irregular shaped contours as well?

Comment: Thanks! I think it would't work because it uses the assumtion that the outer walls are straight lines and that it has a cross-like shape. It maybe could work for irregular shapes if you changed the threshold of extreme points and  made some kind of dictionarry if it had multiple cross-overs (like t #-shape) or none (like a normal square) etc. But it would probably take a lot of work:)

Comment: Great solution. However, if the crossovers shape surrounding some noise point in the image, it may affact 4 values (top, right, left, bottom) extraction. Do you have any ideas to solve it?

Comment: hmm...if there is only a pixel or two you could change the 'if int(i[:,1]) == top' to 'if int(i[:,1])  >= top-2 etc., or you can make additional lists to append values of top, left, right, bottom and select the values that have the highest value and appear more than once or twice in a list.